# capistrano error with unicorn & devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano, unicorn

I am trying to deploy using capistrano and unicorn. Unfortunately, I'm getting the

```
 We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

message. On my development environment everything works. The production.log does not show any errors. The following is the unicorn.log -- there seems to be a problem with Devise? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
E, [2013-04-05T15:45:46.051101 #18179] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
/var/www/releases/20130405154134/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/releases/20130405154134/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:595:in `init_worker_process'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:615:in `worker_loop'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
E, [2013-04-05T15:50:20.918137 #5363] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 18942 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2013-04-05T15:50:20.918399 #5363]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
```

Comment: have you run `bundle install` on the server?

Comment: I have run bundle install one the server and it works without problems.

Comment: Can you post your config/environments/production.rb config/application.rb and Gemfile ?

Comment: any other solutions? bundle install did not help, faced the same issue